# Nested check in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie using javascript and i have a questions. I try to create an object when my variables actually contain values, using the `each` method, which is like this:

```
$('.tab-content.tab-content-guide tr').each(function() {
    var data = $(this);
    var time = data.find('.time').text().trim();
    var title = data.find('.showseries').text().trim();
    var description = data.find('.series_descr').text().trim();

    if (time) {
      if (title) {
        if (description) {
           jsonObj.push({
              'time': time,
              'title': title,
              'description' : description});
        }
      }
    }
});
```

The problem here is that my nested check never reaches at the point to push the actual object. If I try to debug with `console.log` I see that my loop performs only the first check. Can anyone explain me why my nested check doesn't go through?

Here is a sample of the `html` code:

```
<div class="tab-content tab-content-guide">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab_636196032000000000">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class='table' id="table_tab_636196032000000000">
            <tbody id="table_tbody_tab_636196032000000000">
                <tr data-index="0"><td>
                    <p class="time"><time>00:15</time></p>
                </td><td>
                <a href="/minisites/ola-xekolla/">
                    <img src="http://i-cdn.ant1.gr/dbd3f95d-68d9-4849-ad49-a62a00865173/logo_542_456_1.jpg?storage=cloud&w=140&h=140&mode=crop&scale=both&anchor=topcenter&quality=91" alt="Serie" />
                </a>
                </td><td>
                <a href="/minisites/ola-xekolla/">
                    <h5 class="showseries">Some text title</h5>
                    <p class="series_descr">description text here</p>
                </a><div class="greenbutton" onclick="javascript:window.open('/live')"><a href="#">
```

Comment: It seems that `title` is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you add html?

Comment: yes it would help to know what the contents of `.tab-content.tab-content-guide tr` are

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: your code should work fine with the html you posted... (as long as `jsonObj` is defined and your html tags are properly closed)

Comment: Yep, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qudw80u3/1/, assuming you run your code when the document has been loaded and not before.

Comment: Yes my code more or less works. The problem so far was that i wanted the nested if's to avoid empty keys creation in the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be careful of the values that can be returned, for example an empty string is evaluated at false, or certain strings beginning by 0.

if you want to test existence of the jquery elements instead of the values, you can do like this:

```
var time = data.find('.time');
var title = data.find('.showseries');
var description = data.find('.series_descr');

if (time.length) {
  if (title.length) {
    if (description.length) {
       jsonObj.push({
          'time': time.text().trim(),
          'title': title.text().trim(),
          'description' : description.text().trim()});
    }
  }
}
```

Or else you would have to test the value differently, like verbose solutions that i don't like:

```
var time = data.find('.time').text().trim();
if(typeof time !== 'undefined'){
    //...
}
```

EDIT: if you are newbir i recommend also the jquery documentation for the functions find, text, or so, to check what are the default valures returned, proper usage, etc

Comment: you are right. I will need to go through the documentation. I missed that an `undefined` value will stop the next check.

Answer (score 1):

Run this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var jsonObj = [];

  $('.tab-content.tab-content-guide tr').each(function() {
    var data = $(this);
    var time = data.find('.time').text().trim();
    var title = data.find('.showseries').text().trim();
    var description = data.find('.series_descr').text().trim();

    if (time) {
      if (title) {
        if (description) {
          jsonObj.push({
            'time': time,
            'title': title,
            'description' : description});
          }
        }
      }
  });

  console.log(jsonObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content tab-content-guide">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab_636196032000000000">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class='table' id="table_tab_636196032000000000">
            <tbody id="table_tbody_tab_636196032000000000">
                <tr data-index="0"><td>
                    <p class="time"><time>00:15</time></p>
                </td><td>
                <a href="/minisites/ola-xekolla/">
                    <img src="http://i-cdn.ant1.gr/dbd3f95d-68d9-4849-ad49-a62a00865173/logo_542_456_1.jpg?storage=cloud&w=140&h=140&mode=crop&scale=both&anchor=topcenter&quality=91" alt="Serie" />
                </a>
                </td><td>
                <a href="/minisites/ola-xekolla/">
                    <h5 class="showseries">Some text title</h5>
                    <p class="series_descr">description text here</p>
                </a>
                  </td></tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a nested loop. Rather nested if's.

Are you sure your selector gets anything?  (That's usually my problem, the selector returns an empty collection)

Try  putting 
    `console.log($('.tab-content.tab-content-guide tr').length)`

In your code to check that you aren't getting an empty collection.

If length>0,  then, as others have suggested examine your test variables to make sure that they are truthy e.g.

console.log( true && time )

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a comment.